# Force GC to move an object in heap

Tags: c#, unit-testing, garbage-collection

I have a class that contains some delegates, lets call it `EventContainer`. This class is passed to a native C++ dll where the delegates are registered as callbacks for different events.

```
public class EventContainer
{
    public readonly SomeDelegate OnEvent1;
    // ...
}
```

Another class wraps those delegates to proper C# events.

```
public class EventWrapper : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler Event1;

    private GCHandle _gcHandle;

    public EventWrapper()
    {
        var container = new EventContainer(OnEvent1)
        _gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(container);  // gets freed in Dispose
        UnmanagedApi.RegisterEvents(container); // register the delegates (also unregistered in Dispose)
    }

    private void OnEvent1()
    {
        Event1?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    //...
}
```

The container has to be pinned because the memory management of .net sometimes moves objects around in heap and the function pointers on C++ side would become dangling if that happens. Therefore, I want to test if the container (or more precisely the delegates inside it) is pinned (and released) correctly. Testing the *has been released* part is easy but testing the *is properly pinned* part is hard.

I would have to force the GC (or whoever is responsible for compressing the heap) to move the container in heap so the delegates get a new memory address. If the container is pinned, it can't be moved around and therefore invocations of the events on C++ side would still work. However if the container wasn't pinned, the function pointers on C++ side would become dangling and a invocation of them after the container has been moved would cause an `AccessViolationException` (something along those lines).

To test this, I have to force a *move* of the container in heap. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to unit test whether pinning is working? Is not your code/library the owner of `EventContainer`? If yes, why not just pin it and rely on the fact it just works.

Comment: @KonradKokosa _"rely on the fact it just works"_, well if we use this argument the whole point of unit testing becomes obsolete. I'm not trying to test the pinning in itself but that the class behaves correctly. This is not the only class with this behavior in our code base and I'm not the only developer working on it so I would appreciate a unit test that fails if someone forgot to pin or release a handle.

Comment: *"I would appreciate a unit test that fails if someone forgot to pin or release a handle"* - I see. But this is job for code design & static analysis, not for unit tests relying on non-deterministic behavior of hacking the runtime to force memory compaction. Force it by interface/base class/code rules.

Comment: @KonradKokosa base class is indeed a better solution to this. Thanks. Trees and forest...